# Trying to make a working mana regen upgrade

Tags: javascript, html

my first auto clicker is working just fine but when i tried to copy that formula for mana regen my mana regen starts going off as soon as I launch the game. mana regen should only be going off if you spend a skill point on manaregen up.

I've tried copying my autoclicker setinterval thing but the mana regen didn't come out the same. im new at this have no idea how to format it correctly.

here is my javascript:

```
var rebirths = 0;

function buyRebirth() {
    var rebirthCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, rebirths));
    if (cookies >= rebirthCost)
    if (rebirths < 1){
        cookies = cookies - rebirthCost
        HitPoints = HitPoints + 10;
        MaxHitpoints = MaxHitpoints + 10;
        ManaPoints = ManaPoints + 10;
        MaxManapoints = MaxManapoints + 10;
        SkillPoints = SkillPoints + 1;
        rebirths = rebirths + 1;
        document.getElementById("rebirths").innerHTML = rebirths;
        document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;
        document.getElementById("HitPoints").innerHTML = HitPoints;
        document.getElementById("MaxHitpoints").innerHTML = MaxHitpoints;
        document.getElementById("ManaPoints").innerHTML = ManaPoints;
        document.getElementById("MaxManapoints").innerHTML = MaxManapoints;
        document.getElementById("rebirthCost").innerHTML = rebirthCost;
        document.getElementById("SkillPoints").innerHTML = SkillPoints;
    }
    if (cookies >= rebirthCost)
    if(rebirths >= 1){
        cookies = cookies - rebirthCost
        rebirths = rebirths + 1;
        SkillPoints = SkillPoints +1;
        document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = cookies;
        document.getElementById("rebirthCost").innerHTML = rebirthCost;
        document.getElementById("rebirths").innerHTML = rebirths;
        document.getElementById("SkillPoints").innerHTML = SkillPoints;


var ManaPoints = 0;
var SkillPoints = 0;


function ManaPointsregen(){
    if (SkillPoints>0 && rebirths >=1)  
        SkillPoints = SkillPoints - 1;
        ManaPoints = ManaPoints + 1;
        document.getElementById('SkillPoints').innerHTML = SkillPoints;
        document.getElementById("ManaPoints").innerHTML = ManaPoints;
```

near bottom of page this is the autoclicker set up

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    cookieClick(cursors);
}, 1000);
```

this is my html code button for the manaregen upgrade:

```
 <button id="Manaregen" onclick="ManaPointsregen()">Mp regen</button>
                <br />
```

http://prntscr.com/ns5h8j  this is me with just turning it on. it goes up at start.

I expect mana regen to only start going off once you use a skill points on mp regen http://prntscr.com/ns5hj5  . but the actual output mana regen starts going off at the start. I would also like a way for it to stop increasein mabey like creating a MaxManapoints variable and having it stop at <= MaxManapoints.

Comment: Most likely the ManaPointsregen() function is call from cookieClick() or another function which is nested inside.

Comment: can i get help formatting the code correctly? im new to this idk why people spam downvoted sigh. haven't used setinterval alot

Comment: I'm not a big fan of downvoting either. The problem is that you didn't provide the relevant parts of your code so I'm afraid nobody can't help you.

Comment: what else do i need?

Comment: im just trying to fix my function to work. and i posted screen shots what is happening when i start my program. i can add my html code to

Comment: i mostly just wanted someone to tell me where to put / how to format the setinterval so it works with gaining mana

Comment: i asked in my opening statement how to set up setinterval. thats the main reason i posted this. idk how to do it sigh

Comment: because i dont know how to format it

Comment: But nobody in here knows about the inner workings of your program without seeing the code. =) Just posting a fragment of a function and a bit of a setInterval function where nobody can't tell what's it supposed to do isn't helpful. At the moment I just can say that you have set up some sort of button that should fire ManaPointsregen() on click (which in turn should decrease mana points) - but the problem is it's decreasing it without you having clicked on the button. Am I right?

Comment: do I put it on the of my ManaPointsregen function? or somewhere else? sigh i just want this to work

Comment: no its increaseing. if you look at the screen shots

Comment: thats when i first turn on the program and its increaseing constantly

Comment: manaregen should only be going off if you use a skill point on the mp regen button

Comment: in that case i should of left out the setinterval thing for cookieClick. i posted the function because I thought all you needed to set up a setinterval thing is what function its tied to

Comment: and i was told on several earlier ones to not post my whole code just the function that needs to be worked on / fixed. sigh

Comment: Possible reasons for downvotes: (1) using an external image provider rather than the built-in one (these are brittle and may be deleted in the future, damaging the question for future readers); (2) not using a spell-checker; (3) writing in mostly lower case - we encourage readers not to insist on perfect writing, but quite a lot of new users treat Stack Overflow as a chatroom, which some readers do not like. Also (4) complaining about downvotes in the comments, and calling them "spam".

Comment: I didn't know about this my bad. What's the built in image thing.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, you want these two statements to be executed if the value of **SkillPoints** and **rebirths** is at least **1**

```
SkillPoints = SkillPoints - 1;
ManaPoints = ManaPoints + 1;
```

This can be done by wrapping the bits of code you want to be executed inside curly brackets { }.

At the moment there aren't any so in case this condition evaluates to true:

```
if (SkillPoints>0 && rebirths >=1)
```

Javascript will just execute the next line following the if-condition:

```
SkillPoints = SkillPoints - 1;
```

That means every statement after that will be executed regardless of the if-condition:

```
ManaPoints = ManaPoints + 1;
```

Try this:

```
if (SkillPoints>0 && rebirths >=1)
{  
   SkillPoints = SkillPoints - 1;
   ManaPoints = ManaPoints + 1;
}
```

Comment: ok give me a bit thanks ill try that. what should the set interval look like / where should it go

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nsllro       is this right? where should i place this

Comment: If you want this function to be executed every second it should be in the main scope - outside of another function. So from what I can see this looks correct.

Comment: i must have it in the wrong spot ill will try a few more places

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nslq3w    this isnt working. when i press rebirth it takes one skill point automatically then adds one to mana then stops . http://prntscr.com/nslqm0  the one on top is my rebirth counter was using for debugging. its showing that rebirths = 1

Comment: skill points should be left alone until i press any of the things in the skill tree then it should -1 from skillpoints then add to what ever buff i purchased

Comment: the function works perfectly but not when I add the setinterval thing

Comment: its like the function is automatically going off if i have the set interval thing on the javascript

Comment: sigh i really want to continue with this but my mana regen function is not working correctly

Comment: I appreciate the help . i reposted the question because this one got so many downvotes prntscr.com/nsmeyk . would this work somehow? i tried to copy my python code prntscr.com/nsmf4l